# Find full article from PubMed page without any indication?

Tags: research, healthcare-data

I understand that PubMed cites articles that are on other sources, so it might not have a direct link to a full article.

The very question I am asking is actually answered in the FAQs of the site, and there is even a YouTube video that is really easy to understand.

In both the FAQ section and the youtube video, are presented multiple ways to find the full article from a PubMed page, or to find where to buy it.

However, for some pages, such as this one https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7701351/ none of those options seems to be available, and I have no idea where to find, or purchase, such articles.

I understand that some articles might not be made for public use, I would sometimes be glad to pay to read some full articles, if I just knew where to do that.

How do I know where to find full articles in cases such as the one I linked? Or how do I know who to contact to find a way to obtain it?

I should say that Medical Sciences are not my field of study, so there might be something obvious that I don’t know.

Answer (score 1):

The article you linked has the following citation in APA format when clicking "cite".

> Goldman, A. S., Chheda, S., Keeney, S. E., Schmalstieg, F. C., & Schanler, R. J. (1994). Immunologic protection of the premature newborn by human milk. *Seminars in perinatology, 18*(6), 495–501.

Google searching for the journal *Seminars in perinatology* comes up with https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/seminars-in-perinatology

Searching for the volume and issue numbers seems to indicate that the journal website [only goes back as far as  Volume 19 (1995)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/seminars-in-perinatology/issues?page=2) — 1 year before the article you wish to read.

I would suggest that the only way you are going to get hold of a copy of this article is by [contacting Elsevier](https://service.elsevier.com/app/contact/supporthub/sciencedirect/).

Comment: You might want to contact your librarian.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know where to find full articles in cases such as the one I linked? Or how do I know who to contact to find a way to obtain it?

If you can't find the research article via Google, you can always try to contact the authors of the article and ask for a copy of it.

Comment: Ok, but I don’t know who to contact exactly. In the case of the linked article. I just email Mr. Goldman? Or the University of Texas?

Comment: @SpongeTheNumberOf  contact the authors of the article = A S Goldman 1, S Chheda, S E Keeney, F C Schmalstieg, R J Schanler. You can start with ASG.